# Make the address of an objective-C function equal to a pointer of a C function

Tags: objective-c, c, callback, pjsip

I want the address of an objective-C function to equal a pointer to a C function

I can get it to work with the following C function but i would like to use only objective-C if possible

```
//member function from type pjsua_callback (cfg.cb)
void(* on_call_state )(pjsua_call_id call_id, pjsip_event *e)

//Initialize the applications configuration callbacks
app_config->cfg.cb.on_call_state = &on_call_state;
```

.

```
// Callback called by the library when call's state has changed
void on_call_state(pjsua_call_id call_id, pjsip_event *e) {
    NSLog(@"on_call_state, call_id = %d", call_id);
    pjsua_call_info ci;        
    pjsua_call_get_info(call_id, &ci);
    postCallStateNotification(call_id, &ci);    
}
```

I want to achieve this using an objective-c function

```
//objective-c function attempting to recreate the c function
- (void)on_call_state:(pjsua_call_id )call_id andEvent:(pjsip_event *)e{
    NSLog(@"on_call_state, call_id = %d", call_id);
    pjsua_call_info ci;
    pjsua_call_get_info(call_id, &ci);
    [self postCallStateNotification:call_id andCallInfo:&ci];

}
```

Why can't I get the objective-c function to return (void) like the c function and initialize the callback like so (without arguments like in the c function)

```
cfg.cb.on_call_state = &[self on_call_state:andEvent:];
```

i want the cfg.cb.on_call_state to equal the address of my objective-c function

Comment: You can't use methods for your callback because methods have `self` and `cmd` parameters which your callback doesn't.

Comment: Have you considered using blocks?

Comment: Any help out there would be appreciated :)

Comment: I am exactly stuck in this while using pjsip. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

At last I found the solution for this from my own question. For them who are still wondering for the solution, the solution is to make your own C file holding the logic of the callbacks and add your c file into your objective-C code.

So your C file (header file) will look like this

```
//
//  my_app.h
//  AnuranRealSIPOBJ
//
//  Created by Anuran Barman on 01/07/19.
//  Copyright © 2019 Anuran Barman. All rights reserved.
//

#ifndef my_app_h
#define my_app_h

#include <stdio.h>
#import <pjsua.h>

#define THIS_FILE "APP"

static void on_incoming_call(pjsua_acc_id acc_id, pjsua_call_id call_id,
                             pjsip_rx_data *rdata) {
    pjsua_call_info ci;

    PJ_UNUSED_ARG(acc_id);
    PJ_UNUSED_ARG(rdata);

    pjsua_call_get_info(call_id, &ci);

    PJ_LOG(3,(THIS_FILE, "Incoming call from %.*s!!",
              (int)ci.remote_info.slen,
              ci.remote_info.ptr));

    /* Automatically answer incoming calls with 200/OK */
    pjsua_call_answer(call_id, 200, NULL, NULL);
}

/* Callback called by the library when call's state has changed */
static void on_call_state(pjsua_call_id call_id, pjsip_event *e)
{
    pjsua_call_info ci;

    PJ_UNUSED_ARG(e);

    pjsua_call_get_info(call_id, &ci);
    PJ_LOG(3,(THIS_FILE, "Call %d state=%.*s", call_id,
              (int)ci.state_text.slen,
              ci.state_text.ptr));
}

/* Callback called by the library when call's media state has changed */
static void on_call_media_state(pjsua_call_id call_id)
{
    pjsua_call_info ci;

    pjsua_call_get_info(call_id, &ci);

    if (ci.media_status == PJSUA_CALL_MEDIA_ACTIVE) {
        // When media is active, connect call to sound device.
        pjsua_conf_connect(ci.conf_slot, 0);
        pjsua_conf_connect(0, ci.conf_slot);
    }
}

#endif /* my_app_h */
```

After this just add this line where you are configuring your pjsip user agent in your Objective C code which is expecting the pointer to the function:

```
#import "my_app.h"
ua_cfg.cb.on_incoming_call = &on_incoming_call;
ua_cfg.cb.on_call_state = &on_call_state;
ua_cfg.cb.on_call_media_state = &on_call_media_state;
```